# Unable to access commandline arguments in Python 3.6; python launcher the issue?

Tags: python, windows, command-line-arguments

I recently finally moved my default python to 3.6 from 2.7.

Oddly enough, I can't get sys.argv to work correctly.

Short program testargs.py:

```
#!python3
import sys
print("This is the name of the script: ", sys.argv[0])
print("Number of arguments: ", len(sys.argv))
print("The arguments are: " , str(sys.argv))
```

When I run it with arguments ("abcdefg") those arguments don't show up in sys.argv:

```
C:\test>testargs.py abcdefg
This is the name of the script:  C:\test\testargs.py
Number of arguments:  1
The arguments are:  ['C:\\test\\testargs.py']
```

I'm totally confused by this. Any ideas?

I'm using the Python launcher; is that an issue?

When I specifically invoke one or the other Python interpreter, it seems okay:

```
C:\test>c:\Python27\python.exe testargs.py abcdefg
('This is the name of the script: ', 'testargs.py')
('Number of arguments: ', 2)
('The arguments are: ', "['testargs.py', 'abcdefg']")

C:\test>c:\Python36\python.exe testargs.py abcdefg
This is the name of the script:  testargs.py
Number of arguments:  2
The arguments are:  ['testargs.py', 'abcdefg']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a long-standing difficult-to-reproduce bug in Python: https://bugs.python.org/issue7936  . The bug report includes a registry edit that reportedly addresses it but that I don't feel comfortable messing with; so I'll just live with it until I move completely off of Python 2.